Electron Forge complains I need Git (but I have Git installed)
I have my electron.js project completed.  Since I want to have an installer working, I have turned to Electron Forge.
I followed a tutorial online and I got an error in my Microsoft Code IDE that Git was not installed.  But it is installed.  The documentation online suggest that I start a new project from scratch.  How can I resolve this?


I stumbled upon the solution for this.  While preparing to make a more official post on the electron bug list webpage, I tried to run a script that would give me the version of electron, I got this disturbing error:

But, instead of going down that proverbial rabbit hole, I decided to try a CMD interface and see if I could do what was required from just a DOS style command line interface and it worked.  Why it works from a CMD window and not in the "TERMINAL" window inside Microsoft Visual Studio Code IDE, is something I need to learn.  But, as the saying goes, "if it is not broke, don't fix it", and I have a work-around for now.


When you install tools the first time they add entries to the PATH environment variable, it only gets into effect when you restart your terminal. This might be what happened in your case.
